# Xcode 8 Swift 3 building error

Tags: ios, xcode

My code is giving me an error. How do I fix it?

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor (r: 13, g: 214, b: 151)

        view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)


    setupInputsContainerView()

    }

    func setupInputsContainerView() {

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    func  PreferredStatusBarStyle() ->UIStatusBarStyle {
    return.lightContent
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255 , blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

but thing is I'm only getting an error in the extension UIColor {
and the view.backgroundColor = UIColor < is there any fix?

[image]

Comment: You forgot a bracket to close your setupInputsContainerView() function. Add it and see if this resolves your error.

Comment: oh okay ill try

Comment: it gives me more errors if i try doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Like I mentioned in the comment, keep the extension of UIColor outside of `LoginController` scope. The correct code looks like below:

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

    let inputsContainerView: UIView =  {
        let view = UIView()
        let inputsContainerView = UIView()
        inputsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        inputsContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer .masksToBounds = true
        return view

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor (r: 13, g: 214, b: 151)
        view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)

        setupInputsContainerView()
    }

    func setupInputsContainerView() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    }

    func PreferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return.lightContent
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255.0, green: CGFloat(g)/255.0 , blue: CGFloat(b)/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

## Isn't that obvious?

You are missing a trailing curly bracket for closing the `setupInputsContainerView` scope

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor (r: 13, g: 214, b: 151)

    view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)


    setupInputsContainerView()

}

func setupInputsContainerView() {

    //need x, y, width, height constraints
    inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
}

func  PreferredStatusBarStyle() ->UIStatusBarStyle {
    return.lightContent
}

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255 , blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: still giving me error even though i changed to fix it.

Comment: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIColor' with an argument list of type '(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int)' and Declaration is only valid at file scope

Comment: Don't put your extension inside your class scope. It should be like this and then it will work. class Controller: `UIViewController {}` and after it put`extension UIColor {}`

Comment: @Joseph Give me that file and I will fix it for you.

Comment: where can i send it to you?

Comment: Update your question

Comment: I'm new to this I'm asking where should I send my xcode files,

Comment: Well you only need the controller where you're having problems, I do not need the whole source files

Comment: how do i send you one of the error files thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: Zip and upload the project on DropBox and give me the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5rsgiovf55j8ej8/AACf3b-tgPziL5owGHLOIOoCa?dl=0

Comment: @Joseph The answer is updated. If it matches your requirements please vote up and accept the asnwer.

Comment: you sent it back already. i wanna check and make changes to my code.

Comment: Can't you just copy paste the code that I gave you in the file that you had? Don't you see that extension is outside of the scope of `UIViewController` now? You had it inside controller scope as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You pass parameters of type `Int` instead of `CGFloat`. I would recommend to change custom init method singature (use `Int` params instead of `CGFloat`) and convert `Int` parameters to `CGFloat` that are passed to framework init method.

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255.0, green: CGFloat(g)/255.0 , blue: CGFloat(b)/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```